# Fail to assemble Android test build in CI

Tags: android, jenkins, continuous-integration, gradlew

I'm trying to generate an Android release (or debug) build for UI test on Jenkins CI. I use this gradlew command :

`./gradlew assembleDebug assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=debug`

But, i've this error for my **all** dependencies : `validateSigningDebugAndroidTest`.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-clipboard_clipboard:validateSigningDebugAndroidTest'.
> Parent directory of /data/workspace/G-check-commit/android/?/.gradle/daemon/8.0.1/?/.android/debug.keystore.lock does not exist
```

You can see my Jenkins file :

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker { image 'reactnativecommunity/react-native-android' }
    }
    stages {
        stage('setup') {
            steps {
                withEnv(["HOME=${WORKSPACE_TMP}"]) {
                    sh 'npm install'
                }
            }
        }
        stage('e2e tests') {
            steps {
                withEnv(["HOME=${WORKSPACE_TMP}"]) {
                    // Setup emulator
                    sh 'mkdir -p ~/.android && touch ~/.android/repositories.cfg'
                    sh 'echo yes | $ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager --channel=0 --verbose "system-images;android-25;google_apis;armeabi-v7a"'
                    sh '$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager --channel=3 emulator'
                    sh 'echo no | $ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/avdmanager --verbose create avd --force --name "Pixel_API_28_AOSP" --package "system-images;android-25;google_apis;armeabi-v7a" --sdcard 200M --device 11'
                    // Run tests
                    sh 'cd android && chmod +x gradlew && ./gradlew assembleDebug assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=debug'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not really understand this error because the default `./gradlew assembleDebug` work totally without other params.

Anyone can help me ?